# Local to GMT and vice versa- Date and time conversion not working

Tags: java, datetime

I was trying to convert input date time to GMT+0 , later convert that back to its local time. Though local to GMT+0 conversion works, the later conversion-gmt to local fails!

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
System.out.println("my inputTime:"+ sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println("gmt+0 converted time:"+ sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

//now i want to get my local time from this converted gmt+0 standard time
String standdardTimeStr=sdf.format(cal.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date=sdf2.parse(standdardTimeStr);
Calendar cal2= Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.setTime(date);
System.out.println("standard input time:"+ sdf2.format(cal2.getTime()));
sdf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+6")); //or Asia/Dhaka

System.out.println("gmt+6 convertedtime:"+ sdf2.format(cal2.getTime()));
```

And this is my output:

```
my inputTime:2020-07-13T15:02:16.849
gmt+0 converted time:2020-07-13T09:02:16.849
standard input time:2020-07-13T09:02:16.849 //taking upper line as input-gmt+0
gmt+6 convertedtime:2020-07-13T09:02:16.849 //this date was supposed to be same as the first date
```

Please point out what am I doing wrong in coding or conceptually?

Comment: You are using an old and outdated API for date and time operations. There is `java.time` now, so you should be using that instead of `java.util` if you can. There may be situations where you have to stick to the old one, like having to extend an old program.

Comment: I just repeat what deHaar says, because it is very important. You are using an old and outdated API for date and time operations.

Comment: Problem in this line: `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+6"));` It should be `sdf2`, not `sdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the case you want a solution with a modern API, see this commented example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide some fix example datetime String
    String dateTime = "2020-05-08T13:57:06.345";
    
    // create the two time zones needed before
    ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");  // UTC = GMT (+0)
    ZoneId local = ZoneId.systemDefault();  // the zone of your JVM / system
    
    /*
     * then parse the String which doesn't contain information about a zone
     * to an object that just knows date and time
     */
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime);
    // and use that to create a zone-aware object with the same date and time
    ZonedDateTime utcZdt = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, utc);
    // finally adjust its date and time by changing the zone
    ZonedDateTime localZdt = utcZdt.withZoneSameInstant(local);
    
    // then print both results
    System.out.println(utcZdt + "\t==\t" + localZdt);
    
    // and maybe try to use a different output format by defining a custom formatter
    DateTimeFormatter gmtStyleDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSO");
    System.out.println(utcZdt.format(gmtStyleDtf)
                        + "\t==\t" + localZdt.format(gmtStyleDtf));
}
```

which ouputs the following lines **on my system** (might be different on yours due to different time zones):

```
2020-05-08T13:57:06.345Z[UTC]   ==  2020-05-08T15:57:06.345+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
2020-05-08T13:57:06.345GMT      ==  2020-05-08T15:57:06.345GMT+2
```

## EDIT:

Here's a possibility of doing the same thing but just dealing with offsets instead of time zones:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide some fix example datetime String
    String dateTime = "2020-05-08T13:57:06.345";
    
    // create the two offsets needed
    ZoneOffset gmt = ZoneOffset.ofHours(0);  // UTC = GMT (+0)
    ZoneOffset gmtPlusSix = ZoneOffset.ofHours(6);  // Asia/Dhaka ;-)
    
    /*
     * then parse the String which doesn't contain information about a zone
     * to an object that just knows date and time
     * NOTE: this just parses the String and does nothing else
     */
    LocalDateTime justDateAndTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime);
    // and use that to create an offset-aware object with the same date and time
    OffsetDateTime dateAndTimeAndGmtPlusSix = OffsetDateTime.of(justDateAndTime, gmtPlusSix);
    // finally adjust its date and time by changing the offset keeping the instant
    OffsetDateTime dateAndTimeInGmt = dateAndTimeAndGmtPlusSix.withOffsetSameInstant(gmt);
    
    // then print both results
    System.out.println(dateAndTimeAndGmtPlusSix + "\t==\t" + dateAndTimeInGmt);
    
    // and maybe try to use a different output format by defining a custom formatter
    DateTimeFormatter gmtStyleDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSO");
    System.out.println(dateAndTimeAndGmtPlusSix.format(gmtStyleDtf) 
                        + "\t==\t" + dateAndTimeInGmt.format(gmtStyleDtf));
}
```

Output:

```
2020-05-08T13:57:06.345+06:00   ==  2020-05-08T07:57:06.345Z
2020-05-08T13:57:06.345GMT+6    ==  2020-05-08T07:57:06.345GMT
```

Note that a `Z` is equivalent to an offset of GMT/UTC +0.

This way, you could create a method like

```
public static String convert(String datetime, int fromOffset, int toOffset) {
    ZoneOffset fromZoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(fromOffset);
    ZoneOffset toZoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(toOffset);
    OffsetDateTime odt = LocalDateTime.parse(datetime).atOffset(fromZoneOffset);
    return odt.withOffsetSameInstant(toZoneOffset)
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
}
```

maybe handle invalid argument values, use it like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateTime = "2020-05-08T13:57:06.345";
    System.out.println(convert(dateTime, 6, 0)));
}
```

and receive the output

```
2020-05-08T07:57:06.345
```

Comment: let's say `dateTime` string value is client's  dateAndTime and I know his timeZone. Now how can I convert his the `dateTime` string to gmt+0 dateAndTime? `ZonedDateTime utcZdt = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, utc);` it is not changing it, instead, gives me what was in the `dateAndTime`

Comment: the case is, I have to convert a given `dateTime` to a certain timezone like it can be  gmt+0, gmt+6 or anything, lets call it `zoneId`.  now how to do that?

Comment: @user404 Thanks for accepting... You could work with `OffsetDateTime`, too, maybe that would even be a better choice if you are handling offsets like `GMT+0` and `GMT+6`.

Comment: `ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC")` is better written as `ZoneId utc = ZoneOffset.UTC`

Comment: @Andreas Sure, but if OP just knows a GMT offset only, something like a `ZoneOffset gmtPlusSix = ZoneOffset.of("+6");` would be sufficient for an `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: @deHaar, okay. I will check that out

Comment: @user404 See my edit... It's dealing with offsets only

Comment: @deHaar Then `gmtPlusSix = ZoneOffset.ofHours(6)` would be better.

Comment: @Andreas yes, you're right... I was thinking about a method that takes `int` arguments anyway...

Comment: I recommend using Asia/Dhaka for Bangladesh time. Bangladesh hasn’t always been and will probably not always be at offset +06:00. In the summer of 2009 it wasn’t, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're using a `Calendar` object. Javadoc of [`Calendar.getInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance--) says:

> The Calendar returned is based on the **current time** in the default time zone

Which means that calling `cal.setTime(new Date());` is entirely redundant.

But, even worse than that, the following three are all the same:

```java
// The very long way
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
Date date = cal.getTime();

// The long way
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = cal.getTime();

// The simple way
Date date = new Date();
```

---

A `Date` object always stores the date/time in UTC (GMT+0). Time zones are applied when a string is parsed, and when a string is formatted.

Parsing a string that doesn't specify a time zone offset will be parsed in the time zone of the `SimpleDateFormat`, which is the default time zone (aka the "local" time zone) unless otherwise specified, and the parsed value is converted to UTC for storage in a `Date` object.

Formatting a `Date` value to string will always use the time zone of the `SimpleDateFormat`.

---

Cleaning up the code in the question to not use `Calendar`, since that just obfuscates the issue, and commenting it to show what is going on, will answer your question of *"point out what am I doing wrong in coding or conceptually"*:

```java
Date now = new Date();

// Format the date in the local time zone
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
System.out.println("my inputTime:"+ sdf.format(now));

// Format the date in GMT time zone
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println("gmt+0 converted time:"+ sdf.format(now));

// Format the date in GMT time zone (again), since the time     ** ERROR MIGHT **
// zone of the formatter is still set to GMT                    **   BE HERE   **
String standdardTimeStr = sdf.format(now);

// Parse the GMT date string as-if it is in local time zone   ** OR MAYBE HERE **
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = sdf2.parse(standdardTimeStr); // Date value here is wrong

// Format the bad date value back to string in the same time
// zone, which means you get GMT time back, even though that
// is not the value of the `date` variable
System.out.println("standard input time:"+ sdf2.format(date));

// Do it again, same result, because the time zone is changed    ** ERROR HERE **
// on the wrong formatter object
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+6")); //or Asia/Dhaka
System.out.println("gmt+6 convertedtime:"+ sdf2.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to take the string representation of time to convert it back to local. The modified code below will give an idea on the same:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeZoneExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        final Date currentTime = cal.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS Z");
        String timeInCurrentTimeZone = sdf.format(currentTime);
        System.out.println("Time in current time zone: " + timeInCurrentTimeZone);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String timeInGMT = sdf.format(currentTime);
        System.out.println("Time in GMT: " + timeInGMT);
        // Now, take this time in GMT and parse the string -- this is the key, we want to work with the time which got
        // displayed not the internal representation and that's why we will get the time from string!
        Date parsedTime = sdf.parse(timeInGMT);
        String parsedString = sdf.format(parsedTime);
        System.out.println("(GMT) Time in Parsed String: " + parsedString); // here it will show up it in GMT as sdf is still set to GMT
        // Change the zone for sdf
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+6")); // or Asia/Dhaka
        System.out.println("(Local) Time in Parsed String: " + sdf.format(parsedTime)); // here it you will see the zone difference
    }
}
```

**Note**: You will get better picture if you take fixed time instead of current time.